# ondblclick not working in webView for windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I am having a webview element in the app for windows phone 8.1

I am using NavigateToString method to load the html in the webview. This is the tag for double click event.

```
<span id="3" ondblclick="notify(3)">
```

But the event is not being triggered on double click, but it works when I use onclick instead of ondblclick. The html code works fine when I run it on desktop browser and the ondblclick event also works.

Does the webview doesn't support ondblclick? If it does how to get it work?

Answer (score 0):

`webView` does not support `ondbclick`.  You can use `onclick` instead of `ondblclick`, or client add a listener to listen to `dbclick`.